# Exists the way to create a funtion that receive any Crystal Report, C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm using C# and Crystal Reports  to develop a web application, the problem that I have is that the app has a lot of reports, then I need to know It's possible to do something like this:

```
private void showreport (Crystal_Report myReport)
{
   myReportViewer.ReportSource = myReport
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to, but I can tell you that this compiles and works provided you have already prepared the `ReportDocument`:

```
private void showreport (ReportDocument myReport)
{
   myReportViewer.ReportSource = myReport
}
```